# Mute all but my application

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, audio, directx

I made little sound generator in C# 4.0 using DirectSound.
I would like to mute all other sounds. I want only my application to be able to emit sounds.

How to do it?

I know how to pInvoke so you can give me unmanaged code.

Comment: What versions of Windows are you aiming to support? Vista and newer?

Comment: You realize this is only possible under Vista/7, right?

Comment: Hopefully, there is no way for you to do that. No (non-O/S) application should be allowed to decide what other applications can or cannot do.

Comment: What if two programs did this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - using WASAPI (in Vista, 7, and 2008) programs can gain exclusive access to audio devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properly designed programs either stop playing back sound when their main window becomes deactivated.  Or use IDirectSound::SetCooperativeLevel() so they play nice with other programs that want to be heard.

You are asking how to make a improperly designed program behave nicely.  With a bit of a hint that you don't contemplate being nice yourself.  Teaching that uncooperative program a lesson is simple, run its uninstaller.  Avoid being the victim of that same advice.

Comment: Or: a properly designed program will still play sound. Because it's required/needed in case of an alarm situation? Or an incoming phone call? Or...? As a user, I *want* such sounds to still play even if I'm currently running an app that decided to silence all others.